# Create new scope in service

Tags: angularjs

I have a `Service`, that receiving a text string. I have cached in `$templateCache` template that I can access to from Service.

So, my goal is create new scope with passed text and using `$compile` service apply it to template. Then, append it to specified element.

I understand, that is great to use `ngRepeat` and `Controller` here, but for architecture reasons I had to use Service.

Maybe anybody have any good advices, which practice is the best?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Could you provide a code example to demonstrate what you are asking?

Comment: it's better to use directive here!

Comment: I haven't any code yet, because I can't catch the way I should go to)

Comment: @STEVER, I thought about that. But I can't access to directive from service...

Comment: Best practices dictate that if you are going to work with DOM elements, you must use directives. To integrate the directives with the service just use an event-driven approach.

Comment: @SemyonVyskubov, you don't need to access directive from service.

Comment: just provide the idea of full task please

Answer (score 0):

best practice in your case is to listen for $destroy, and cleanup properly.

*update*

because your goal is to use $compile, the best practice in your case is to listen for $destroy and cleanup properly.